# what does double question marks mean in c#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “??” operator for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827454/what-is-the-operator-for)

Debugging some code and found ?? inside the code. What does this mean?

Comment: This question is asked more than ten times in stackoverflow itself. Some of them are here. 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827454/what-is-the-operator-for 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925726/coalesce-operator-in-c 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770096/what-does-mean.

Answer (score 19):

`??` is  the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) for nullable types.

```
object obj = canBeNull ?? alternative;

// equivalent to:
object obj = canBeNull != null ? canBeNull : alternative;
```

Answer (score 5):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx refer to this for description. it's an operator

The `??` operator defines the default value to be returned when a nullable type is assigned to a non-nullable type.

```
    // ?? operator example.
    int x = null;

    // y = x, unless x is null, in which case y = -1.
    int y = x ?? -1;

    // Assign i to return value of method, unless
    // return value is null, in which case assign
    // default value of int to i.
    int i = GetNullableInt() ?? default(int);

    string s = GetStringValue();
    // ?? also works with reference types. 
    // Display contents of s, unless s is null, 
    // in which case display "Unspecified".
    Console.WriteLine(s ?? "Unspecified");
```